# How to fix unrecognized tag in settings xml?

Tags: java, xml, maven, settings

I have setting.xml

```
<settings
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>Nexus.Codehaus Snapshots</id>
            <name>Nexus Mirror of Codehaus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://build/nexus/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots</url>
            <mirrorOf>Codehaus Snapshots</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>Nexus</id>
            <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
            <url>http://nexus.other.com/content/groups/public</url>
            <mirrorOf>Nexus</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <server>
        <id>TomcatServer</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>quickBuild</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
                <pmd.skip>true</pmd.skip>
                <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
                <findbugs.skip>true</findbugs.skip>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>some</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>some2</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>some3</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>some4</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>some5</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>repository-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
                    <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

At start of maven build I have a message:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'server' (position: START_TAG seen ...</mirrors>\r\n\t\r\n\t<server>... @31:10)  @ D:\directory\.m2\settings.xml, line 31, column 10
[WARNING]
```

I do not undestand why? As I understand server tag and mirrors are valid (I think so because plugins and dependency resolving works). How I can fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<server>` tag must be contained in a `<servers>` tag.

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

See [the Maven `settings.xml` doc](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of the top elements under settings:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

You can easily find top elements information from  https://maven.apache.org/settings.html